# Xcode 7.1 iOS 9.1 Simulator transparent

Tags: ios, xcode

I just recognized that I can see thru the iOS Simulator if an UIView is defined with (semi-) transparent content. But I can not make a screenshot of it, on the screenshot the effect is gone.

[image: Here the screenshot]

The (custom) navigation bar on top has alpha set to CGFloat(0.9).

Here a screenshot taken with an iPhone 6:

[image]

Zoom in and you can see thru the simulator window on Xcode. I assume this is a bug, or is it intended behavior of the OS X transparency effects? If it is intended, can I turn it off?

Comment: Maybe `self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO` ?

Comment: There is no navigation bar, this is a custom created UIView which mimics a navigation bar. But this is not the point - I can see _thru_ the simulator window on Xcode. This is not an iOS problem, but a iOS simulator problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I have found the problem. Actually it is not a transparency effect but a display problem. I am using an iMac 27inch with an IPS LCD display, which suffers heavily from "screen burning". Xcode is standing on this position for hours so it burned in into the display. That's why I can not make a screenshot - it is a hardware problem.

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5255653?tstart=0

Answer (score 0):

Yeah this is going to be a hardware / screen problem. Should not translate to your app.